# On TestNG using new JVM thread/instance for each test

Tags: java, testng

I'm running tests on a legacy system that has many static objects and uses several singletons... i'm not able to detect them all, so this leads to errors when running my test suite.

I'm using eclipse, testng and Mockito. To run the test we we use eclipse run configurations and/or gradle build.

Issue:

- when i run my tests as single test (Run as -> TestNG test) it's working properly (it's ok, its' working)
- when i use my suite.xml file the tests fail because some singletons/static variables still are mocked/have the wrong content/are wrong initialized

**how can i create a new JVM for each test?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test p1t1">
        <classes>
            <class name="package1.Test1"/> <!-- test ok -->
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test p1t2">
        <classes>
            <class name="package1.Test2"/> <!-- will fail now -->
        </classes>
    </test>             
</suite>
```

when i swap my execution order the problem occurs on the other side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test p1t2">
        <classes>
            <class name="package1.Test2"/> <!-- test now ok -->
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test p1t1">
        <classes>
            <class name="package1.Test1"/> <!-- will fail now instead -->
        </classes>
    </test>             
</suite>
```

Comment: i was hoping for a test parameter like `<test name="test xy" fork="true">` to create a new jvm for each test

Comment: any workaround would be helpful... it can be solved in the classes or somewhere else as well, it hasn't to be solved in the `suite.xml` file...

Comment: i found an answer on my problem, but that simply says: "bad luck poor guy, it's not working with suites"... can someone prove him to be wrong? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/testng-not-forking-test-processes/11929

Comment: True, TestNG doesn't fork multiple suite files.  Personally, i don't see why you would need to do that anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and set [`reuseForks`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reuseForks) to "false":

> Indicates if forked VMs can be reused. If set to "false", a new VM is forked for each test class to be executed. If set to "true", up to `forkCount` VMs will be forked and then reused to execute all tests.

e.g.:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <includes>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [Maven Surefire Plugin – Fork Options and Parallel Test Execution](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) for more details.

Comment: our tests are started with the gradle toolkit even though we run the test suite manually from eclipse - is there a way to set these parameters on other places, namly in gradle and eclipse run configurations? (+1)

Comment: @MartinFrank I haven't used Gradle enough to know for sure but you should be able to use Surefire programmatically. You should find insight on how to do so from the Maven Surefire and Maven Surefire Plugin tests (e.g. [maven-surefire/SurefirePluginTest.java at surefire-2.19.1_vote-2 · apache/maven-surefire](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1_vote-2/maven-surefire-plugin/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefirePluginTest.java)).

Comment: thank you very much - as it seems i have to cope with that problem, without surefire - i'll try to eleminate all singletons and statics during @afterClass in testng... hopefully that will work

Comment: should this question be deleted now?

Comment: @MartinFrank Why would we want to delete the question? Definitely not. Others will have the same or similar question and will search online and hopefully find this question of yours with the answers. Some may be using Maven and can benefit from my answer, others may benefit from djangofan's answer from his experiences. Please do not delete.

Comment: thanks for your reply and thank you for your valuable input even though there seems to be no solution for the problem named atop (i could solve it be diligently reset all static variables and resetting all singletons)

Answer (score 1):

One way I have got around that is to have a Spring wired singleton that is **static** and therefore can be shared with TestNG threading, which gets wired differently (with Guice??).  Kindof a hack though, but it worked for me.  Spring and TestNG don't play together perfectly, as you know, in and around the **@Configuration** phase of tests, and the details of that I still haven't fully delved into.

Comment: thanky ou for your support(+1) ...i **have to use** gradle and no more (my boss is quite picky)... i'll try to eleminate and reset all singletons during @AfterClass...

Comment: should this question be deleted now?

Comment: No, no need to delete.  This info might be useful to others.

Comment: thanks for your reply and thank you for your valuable input even though there seems to be no solution for the problem named atop (i could solve it be diligently reset all static variables and resetting all singletons)

Comment: @MartinFrank  yes, it is quite annoying that TestNG and Spring don't play together better...